# How to calculate api latency from tomcat server weblogs via elastic search Kibana?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, tomcat, kibana, aws-elasticsearch

I have been asked to help getting latency KPI put together for key API  endpoints. And transformed into a format and location where we can more easily track api latency.

BUT,

I am not able to get any understanding out of the data. My data looks like below:
Need your advice to capture details from below data, and what actually I could do from it.
[image: MY DATA LOOKS SIMILAR TO THIS IMAGE IN KIBANA]

Comment: You need to parse the message (if you have the duration for the service in it).

Comment: ok, I will. check and update shortly. Thanks for your reply